# Error from send Net.Mail from gmail with attachment

Tags: c#

I don't send gmail from four attachment

```
{            
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress(Form4.email);
    mail.To.Add("my@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Subject";
    mail.Body = "See attachment";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment1;
attachment1 = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C:/Tabliczka_Mnozenia/key_product.crt");
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment1);
[...More 3 Attachment]
SmtpServer.Port = 465; 
SmtpServer.Credentials = new  System.Net.NetworkCredential("my@gmail.com", "Password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Timeout = 90000;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

Error send:[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_g0fg1JrDeHMaoM7uOnL4UUBcp4ycfp3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you configured your Google Account `=> Security => Less secure app access`, setting it to `ON`? Also, are you sure about this: `mail.From = new MailAddress(Form4.email);`? Have you verified that you're getting a correct string here?

Comment: secure app access is correct. MailAdress(Form4.email); this function get e-mail correct string. Form4.email is verified.

Comment: Then test post 587 first and, if it still fails because of a connection closed (failed handshake, apparently), try port 25 that auto-redirects on TLS protocol type.

Comment: Error send port 587 or 25: [link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v0foC9loG-DYIGqYfYPGe8AUfts_Rn1p

Comment: [File types blocked in Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en). [Send attachments with your Gmail message](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584)

Comment: File blocked *.dll, Attachement size is 1 KB i am try rename file types

Comment: Next step Rename file types, port 587 and 465 error

Comment: choose Project debug to relase and correct send e-mail